# Discretized continuous Fourier transform with numpy

Tags: math, numpy, matplotlib, fft, continuous-fourier

Consider a function f(t), how do I compute the continuous Fouriertransform g(w) and plot it (using numpy and matplotlib)?

[image]

This or the inverse problem (g(w) given, plot of f(t) unknown) occurs if there exists no analytical solution to the Fourier Integral.

Comment: +1 So you write a question and then answer it by yourself?

Comment: Yes, I read that people are encouraged to do so. This was one of the few numpy/matplotlib problems I didn't find a solution for by using google. So i thought I'd share the solution. The page where I read about answering your own question was here http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Hi, would you be so kind to have a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428886/discrete-fourier-transfromation-from-a-list-of-x-y-points)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the [numpy FFT module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html) for that, but have to do some extra work. First let's look at the Fourier integral and discretize it:
[image]
Here k,m are integers and N the number of data points for f(t). Using this discretization we get
[image]

The sum in the last expression is exactly the Discrete Fourier Transformation (DFT) numpy uses (see section "Implementation details" of the [numpy FFT module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html)).
With this knowledge we can write the following python script

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

#Consider function f(t)=1/(t^2+1)
#We want to compute the Fourier transform g(w)

#Discretize time t
t0=-100.
dt=0.001
t=np.arange(t0,-t0,dt)
#Define function
f=1./(t**2+1.)

#Compute Fourier transform by numpy's FFT function
g=np.fft.fft(f)
#frequency normalization factor is 2*np.pi/dt
w = np.fft.fftfreq(f.size)*2*np.pi/dt


#In order to get a discretisation of the continuous Fourier transform
#we need to multiply g by a phase factor
g*=dt*np.exp(-complex(0,1)*w*t0)/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))

#Plot Result
pl.scatter(w,g,color="r")
#For comparison we plot the analytical solution
pl.plot(w,np.exp(-np.abs(w))*np.sqrt(np.pi/2),color="g")

pl.gca().set_xlim(-10,10)
pl.show()
pl.close()
```

The resulting plot shows that the script works [image]

Comment: +1 For nice way of publishing a question and answering it by yourself!

Comment: If you're computing a (discreticized) FT this way, can you include frequencies smaller than 1 or periods that are multiples of the length of the input array? Perhaps you could help answering this question: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/looking-for-cycles-of-periods-longer-than-the-input-signal-length

Comment: Yeah, for a frequency-to-time-Fourier-Transform you SHOULD include small frequencies, otherwise your result for long times will not be very good. I think your question is not directly related, and I cannot answer it without putting considerable research into it myself, sorry.

Comment: I thought it was related, because someone suggested in the comments that the continuous transform could be the solution, because it can consider sines of periods longer than the input signal, while the discrete transform does not go beyond the signal length. I'm not if or how the discreticised continuous transform can do the same, but I will investigate...

Comment: What is that green horizontal line?

Comment: @omehoque: That is because the frequency array w is not ordered.

Comment: @thomasfermi: Thanks. I eventually figured it out. And thanks again for the excellent question and answer.

Comment: Not a Python question, but what if i do not want the time discretization symmetric about zero but with an offset, i.e. `t=offset + np.arange(t0,-t0,dt)`. What will the corresponding omegas be then?

Comment: @Christoph90: If you do that, you will have the same frequencies and you will compute the Fourier transform of f(t-offset) instead of f(t)