# Discrete fourier transformation from a list of x-y points

Tags: python, math, numpy

What I'm trying to do is, from a list of x-y points that has a periodic pattern, calculate the period. With my limited mathematics knowledge I know that Fourier Transformation can do this sort of thing.

I'm writing Python code.

I found a related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077913/discretized-continuous-fourier-transform-with-numpy), but it uses an evenly-distributed x axis, i.e. `dt` is fixed, which isn't the case for me. Since I don't really understand the math behind it, I'm not sure if it would work properly in my code.

My question is, does it work? Or, is there some method in `numpy` that already does my work? Or, how can I do it?

**EDIT:** All values are Pythonic `float` (i.e. double-precision)

Comment: can you post this list ?

Comment: @Moritz Not really... It contains thousands of points... When plotted there is visually a clear periodic pattern

Comment: then post the plot at least so we know what you dealing with ...

Comment: Interpolating and resampling the data can be one solution. I have tried to provide an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53772921/4999991).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For samples that are not evenly spaced, you can use [`scipy.signal.lombscargle`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lombscargle.html) to compute the [Lomb-Scargle periodogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-squares_spectral_analysis).  Here's an example, with a signal whose
dominant frequency is 2.5 rad/s.

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lombscargle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


np.random.seed(12345)

n = 100
x = np.sort(10*np.random.rand(n))
# Dominant periodic signal
y = np.sin(2.5*x)  
# Add some smaller periodic components
y += 0.15*np.cos(0.75*x) + 0.2*np.sin(4*x+.1)
# Add some noise
y += 0.2*np.random.randn(x.size)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x, y, 'b')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid()

dxmin = np.diff(x).min()
duration = x.ptp()
freqs = np.linspace(1/duration, n/duration, 5*n)
periodogram = lombscargle(x, y, freqs)

kmax = periodogram.argmax()
print("%8.3f" % (freqs[kmax],))

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(freqs, np.sqrt(4*periodogram/(5*n)))
plt.xlabel('Frequency (rad/s)')
plt.grid()
plt.axvline(freqs[kmax], color='r', alpha=0.25)
plt.show()
```

The script prints `2.497` and generates the following plots:

[image: plot of the signal]

[image: plot of the Lomb-Scargle periodogram]

Comment: Not sure what does `from __future__ import division` do here though? I don't seem to need it.

Comment: @MichaelKim That's a habit I developed from frequently working with both Python 2 and Python 3.  As it is, this script doesn't need that import, but if you changed the script in such a way that, say, `duration` became an integer greater than 1, then without that import of `division`, the expression `1/duration` would be 0.  The alternative way of "version-proofing" the code would be to change the expression to `1.0/duration`, but I'm getting used to the Python 3 style, so I use the import of `division`.

Comment: I'm a little late to the game, but what is the unit of the y-axis? Similar to a power spectrum the square of the original unit?

Answer (score 1):

As starting point:

- (I assume all coordinates are positive and integer, otherwise map them to reasonable range like 0..4095)
- find max coordinates xMax, yMax in list
- make 2D array with dimensions yMax, xMax
- fill it with zeros
- walk through you list, set array elements, corresponding to coordinates, to 1
- make 2D Fourier transform
- look for peculiarities (peaks) in FT result

Comment: What is coordinate range?

Answer (score 0):

This page from Scipy shows you basic knowledge of how Discrete Fourier Transform works:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/routines.fft.html

They also provide API for using DFT. For your case, you should look at how to use fft2.

Comment: Those are for evenly spaced samples.

Comment: Does not seem to work with float-point values, only for integers